# ng-stripe-checkout module import in angular 9

Tags: npm, node-modules, angular9

I have problem with build after upgrading to Angular9. This is the error I get:

> ERROR in node_modules/ng-stripe-checkout/src/stripe-checkout.module.d.ts:1:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

any ideas?

Comment: Contact the library author. The library needs to build properly.